# Где Firefox Mozilla хранит файл настроек proxy и можно ли его нормально прочитать программой Блокнот?

Tags: proxy, firefox, settings

Дело в том, что по работе мне постоянно приходится прописывать эти чертовы прокси вручную, уже надоело - хочу автоматизировать этот процесс. Напишу специальную программу. Либо создам инсталлятор. Буду рад любой наводке по той и другой теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Windows

Для текущего пользователя

%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ijd7sbek.default\prefs.js

Для Linux

Для текущего пользователя

~/.mozilla/firefox/ijd7sbek.default/prefs.js

Для всех пользователей

/etc/firefox/syspref.js

Для файлов

секция user_pref(network.proxy.параметр,"Значение")

Где

- параметр - параметр прокси
- Значение - значение параметра

Рекомендую почитать документацию по этим файлам. Так же встречал PowerShell скрипт для изменения параметров. Возможно поможет https://superuser.com/questions/993614/powershell-editing-firefox-prefs-js-file